# How to store user logging

Tags: java, database, nosql, neo4j

Recently, our system need to store millions record per day. Each record is very simple, the userid and the clicked weburl. After that we use some machine learning algorithms on the data logs.
We tried neo4j, but the query time is very slow. For example : get all pair userid view same weburl.
So any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have made it for a database that support more than 1 billion transactions per days:

Make a frontal table like a buffer named TBUFFER for example.
In that table, insert informations that you want to insert in your log table.

Each seconds, from a job, read the TBUFFER and distribute the datas in yours final tables.
Why doing that ? To be able to make massive insert.

The key is to do insert by packet to divide numbers of transaction and then locks.

You can also pass XML datas, that contain many user logging to insert, to your database and insert it using a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think Neo4j is not the right database to store billions of simple, non-connected records. Use a key-value store (like riak, redis etc) for that.